# Javascript chaining pattern return equivalent of this object instead of returning this

Tags: javascript

While implementing functions via chaining pattern it is not advisable to return "this" object if your function is to used by external sources(untrustable sources).
Instead one should return equivalent of "this" like in the following code.

```
var calc = function (start){
        var that = this;
        this.add = function(x){
         start = start + x;
         return that;  
        };

        this.multiply= function(x){
          start = start * x;
          return that;
        };
     };
```

How does returning "that" instead of "this" make any difference as both of them are of same reference.

Comment: Yeah. This advise makes no sense. He's probably thinking of losing the `this` reference but that's not a problem in this use-case.

Comment: Where did you read this advice?

Comment: came across in a pluralsight vedio on javascript design patterns by aaron powell.

Comment: Are you sure the advice didn't actually mean you should *clone* the object instead of modifying and returning the current instance? I.e. `this.multiply = function(x) { return new calc(start * x); }`

Comment: We are not cloning the object as it clear from the code itself.
reason for using that instead of this is because so that no one can change value of this.
Which does not make sense as they both are of same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` in JavaScript is object on which given function was called.
[How this works in JavaScript](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)